# How can I expose Magento2.2.4 on static ip address with Apache2 and Centos 6?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, magento2.2.4

Actually when I digit my static ip adress remotely ( http://11.11.11.11:80 ) Magento rewrite it in htttp://localhost:80.
Is there a configuration to unchange the static ip address like http://11.11.11.11:80/products....

Thanks

Comment: use hosts file , base url and DNS

Answer (score 0):

resolved with base url's Magento 2 configuration!
instead of `/localhost` I inserted `/11.11.11.11` ( my static ip address )